# Convert data {"a"="1","b"="2","c"="3"} to sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of data with each cell containing `{"a"="a1","b"="b1","c"="c1"}`, including the curly braces and where "a", "b", "c" are the same in each cell. Is it possible to create a sheet with columns for a, b and c, and have each row contain the corresponding a1 etc?

In the image below, column A is the input and columns C, D, E are desired output.

[image: input and output]

Comment: Splitting data from one column into several columns is very possible in Excel. It's a little hard to visualize your setup from the way you've typed it up in your question, can you post a screenshot of (a) what you have now, and (b) one row broken up the way you'd like?

Comment: Better share some sample data or Screen Shot along with expected results !!

Comment: Thanks. I've included an image of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is just string manipulation. All you need is `MID`, and the proper combination of counting functions to feed to `MID` to tell it which strings to split out. Luckily you have very consistent inputs so this isn't very hard to do.

Move your first input from `A1` to `A2`.

Formula for `C2`:

`=MID(A2,FIND("Animal",A2)+10,FIND("Food",A2)-FIND("Animal",A2)-14)`

`D2`:

`=MID(A2,FIND("Food",A2)+8,FIND("Use",A2)-FIND("Food",A2)-12)`

`E2`:

`=MID(A2,FIND("Use",A2)+7,LEN(A2)-FIND("Use",A2)-8)`

Copy those three formulas down to the end of your data.

[image: Voila]

Answer (score -1):

Select all data. Copy. 
In notepad or notepad++ :
paste > ctrl+h (replace) : "{" -> "" , enter, then > ctrl+h (replace) : "}" -> "" , enter . > Select all, copy..

then in excel :
paste > done.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work.